# Vue js Custom function in vue dropzone

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using vue-dropzone in v-for loop
How can I pass index of each loop as a parameter to @vdropzone-complete function

this is my code

```
<vue-dropzone 
      ref="dropzone" 
      id="drop1" 
      :include-styling="false"
      :options="dropOptions" 
       v-on:vdropzone-removed-file="removeThisFile"
       @vdropzone-complete="afterComplete(file, index)">
</vue-dropzone>
```

And this is my after complete function

```
afterComplete(file, index) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(file);
}
```

I can't pass file as parameter of afterComplete function

Answer (score 0):

You can access the index in your for loop,

```
<div 
  v-for="{dropzone, index} in dropzones
  :key="index"
>
  <vue-dropzone 
    ref="dropzone" 
    id="drop1" 
    :include-styling="false"
    :options="dropOptions" 
    v-on:vdropzone-removed-file="removeThisFile"
    @vdropzone-complete="afterComplete(file, index)">
  </vue-dropzone>
</div>
```

Relative to the [doc](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

Comment: thanks for your replay, This i already i tried.
This way i am not able to get file at method afterComplete